# Why is Elastic beanstalk app creation failing at [InstallDependency] python3.8

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-3.8

I've rebuilt the requirements.txt multiple times, and removed and re-created pipenv, but still every time I build the deployment package for elastic beanstalk, the deployment fails giving this error:

```
2021/12/14 18:31:40.411896 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with Pipfile file with error Command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/python3.8 -m pipenv install --skip-lock failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.8, but you are using unknown (/var/app/s/.venv/bin/python).
  $ pipenv --rm and rebuilding the virtual environment may resolve the issue.
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.
Error while executing command /var/app/staging/.venv/bin/python -c import sysconfig, distutils.sysconfig, io, json, sys; paths = {u'purelib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=0)),u'stdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')),u'platlib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=1)),u'platstdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('platstdlib')),u'include': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=0)),u'platinclude': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=1)),u'scripts': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('scripts')),u'py_version_short': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_version()), }; value = u'{0}'.format(json.dumps(paths));fh = io.open('/tmp/tmpn2omzq7a.json', 'w'); fh.write(value); fh.close():Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 513, in _create_subprocess
    c = _spawn_subprocess(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 190, in _spawn_subprocess
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/var/app/staging/.venv/bin/python'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/contextmanagers.py", line 205, in spinner
    yield _spinner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 618, in run
    return _create_subprocess(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 524, in _create_subprocess
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 513, in _create_subprocess
    c = _spawn_subprocess(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 190, in _spawn_subprocess
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/var/app/staging/.venv/bin/python'

[KTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    cli()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 232, in install
    retcode = do_install(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2052, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1305, in do_init
    do_install_dependencies(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 870, in do_install_dependencies
    batch_install(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 734, in batch_install
    deps_to_install = [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 735, in <listcomp>
    dep for dep in deps_to_install if not project.environment.is_satisfied(dep)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 376, in environment
    self._environment = self.get_environment(allow_global=allow_global)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 360, in get_environment
    environment = Environment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 73, in __init__
    self._base_paths = self.get_paths()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 364, in get_paths
    c = vistir.misc.run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 618, in run
    return _create_subprocess(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 524, in _create_subprocess
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 513, in _create_subprocess
    c = _spawn_subprocess(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/vistir/misc.py", line 190, in _spawn_subprocess
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/var/app/staging/.venv/bin/python'
```

I've worked throuh issues with my ebextensions and I'm sure that the python version in the local venv *is* 3.8, all libs are installed correctly, and the code is working locally.

Comment: Hi, i'm struggling with aws elastic beanstalk for while now, but when i deployed my app i didn't use pipenv, in my machine i used anaconda but for deploy i only made the zip files with the code, without any env information. When the elastic beanstalk is on init he search the requirements.txt and install them without any problem, so try to upload the code without pipenv folder

Comment: @Luiz thanks, I tried it and it hasn't made a difference